# Would a Linus Roadster work on an off-road country environment?

Tags: mountain-bike, off-road

Would a bicycle like a Linus Roadster Classic handle well on an off-road country environment or would you recommend a mountain bike for this?

Comment: do you mean unpaved roads or unpaved trails?

Comment: Totally depends on the surface you intend to ride.   Is it dirt, mud, packed or loose?    I've ridden a road bike on an offroad trail and it was workable, though not fast.

Comment: On an unpaved trail, its dirt, packed but might have like branches and that sort of thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Linus Roadster is not the bike I'd choose for rural poor quality tarmac, gravel roads or packed dirt trails.

The stock 32mm tires do give a bit more volume than standard road size tires to soak up bumps a little (they are about the the same size as cyclo-cross tires ) but they are slicks designed for paved roads. The main problems are the single speed drivetrain and rear wheel only coaster brake. (There's also the fact that the bike screams *urban hipster!!!*)

You don't need a full-on mountain bike for poor quality tarmac, gravel roads or packed dirt trails as long as they are relatively smooth without big bumps and holes. If you want flat bars a hybrid would work well. You don't need a suspension fork and tires 35-40mm wide with a medium tread pattern will be fine. If you want drop bars gravel bikes are ideal for these sorts or surfaces as well.

Comment: If you did want something with the stylishness of the Linus Roadster that would be more suitable for country jaunts, the 7i would be worth looking at. I wouldn’t take it on a ride where I expected to be doing major lifting or dropping of the front wheel, but mine handles smoothish unsealed surfaces fine and in comfort.

Answer (score 2):

based on the 2020 linus roadster, you would be struggling.  it has 32mm wide tires and you would want something at least wider than 45mm (1.75 in).  even a crummy mountain bike would ride better off-road than the roadster.

Comment: I am unclear as to why this answer got downvoted. Can anyone confirm the accuracy of the answer Is 32mm wide tires not good enough for dirt trails with ups and downs?

Comment: There are lots of dirt surfaces for which “you need a 45mm tire” is wrong. Cyclocross races even limit to 33mm.

Comment: The question gives no indication as to the skills of the OP - asserting "you would be struggling"  could be wrong.  (While not my first choice for such conditions, the biggest struggle I would have on that bike is making sure no one I knew saw me, but I respect other peoples have different priorities to mine, they may decide that the compromise is worth it.)  Tire size, while relevant, is no more or less important than things like single speed, coaster brakes which are not mentioned.

Comment: I think the reason for tire width limit in cyclocross is to stop participants from using wider tires, and in grand scheme of things, to keep it as separate discipline from cross country MTB. If wide tires didn't have benefits, the rule wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Wider tires certainly have their benefits, and I agree that distinguishing cyclocross from mountain biking is the reason for the tire size limit. Neither of those take away from the fact that 32mm is plenty for many “off-road” surfaces.